# adding two javascript functions to one submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call a form validate function, then a tracking code function with one onsubmit call.  But it doesn't work.  The form validation works, but the tracking function does not.  Can I put the tracking function in the validation function??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
x=document.myForm

customercountry=x.country.value

submitOK="True"

if (customercountry == "") 
 {
 alert("Please select a country.")
 submitOK="False"
 }

if (submitOK=="False")
 {
 return false
 }

}
</script>


<form name=myForm method="post" onsubmit="return validate() && _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'check1', 'clicked'])" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?action=2">
<select name="country">
<?php echocountries(); ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. This won't work unless both of those functions returned a Boolean, then `return [true | false]` would work. So basically, call your other function inside `validate()`:

```
onsubmit="return validate()"
```

Then in `validate()` (*note:* you want to make sure this returns `true` of `false`):

```
function validate() {  
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'check1', 'clicked']); // Assuming this is a valid function.
    // Other validate code.
}
```